# Differentiating organizer as attendee when creating an event on Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When creating an event using the Create Event endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), is there a way to differentiate between an event that has the organizer as an attendee vs. an event that does not?

It seems like despite sending the organizer as part of the attendees list as part of the request payload, they do not show up as an attendee in the created event (or in the ICS file sent to other attendees via email) but only as the organizer.

The result for creating the same event without sending the organizer as attendee are identical, so there is no way of knowing whether the organizer is an attendee or not.

EDIT: The API response DOES differ and shows the right attendees list based on the request payload, but the email and ICS files do no (both cases do not show the organizer as an attendee).

Comment: Try giving the organizer details in the payload both in organizer property and attendees property so that you will be getting the organizer as an attendee for all events.

Comment: It works Shiva :)

Comment: Hello Shiva. I have tried this and got the same result - The API responds correctly, but the ICS file sent via email to the other attendees does not contain the organizer as attendee, despite the request putting them both as organizer and attendee.

Comment: Sorry I did not tag you: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity

Comment: I tested this in my environment and its working. I see the attendees details in the ICS file.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity thanks for the reply. Can you share a request mock with the payload you were using? I tried to send an `event` object with 

`{organizer: { emailAddress: { address: 'person1@mail.com' } }, attendees: [ {emailAddress: { address: 'person1@mail.com', type: 'required' }, {emailAddress: { address: 'person2@mail.com', type: 'required' }, {emailAddress: { address: 'person3@mail.com', type: 'optional' }] }`

but the ICS file sent to person2 and person3 only listed person2 and person3 as attendees. person1 was only an organizer.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity and forgot to mention the endpoint i am using is `/me/calendars/{id}/events` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I am also using almost the same endpoint `/me/calendars/events` and using the below payload `{organizer: { emailAddress: { address: 'person1@mail.com' } }, attendees: [ {emailAddress: { address: 'person1@mail.com', type: 'required' }, {emailAddress: { address: 'person2@mail.com', type: 'required' }, {emailAddress: { address: 'person3@mail.com', type: 'optional' }] }` but I am able to see it in ics file person1 as organizer as I have created using that account and also see the attendees list.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity well then i am stumped. tried again, with the `/me/calendar/events` as well and gotten the same issue. I also tried api version `1.0` and the `beta` and I am still getting a good response from the API but the ICS file in the email contains only the other 2 persons as attendees. Could this be related to some internal account settings of the o365 organization? Otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: The ics file considers organizer as different and attendees as different so you cannot get the organizer as attendee in ics.

Comment: For more information about ics, you can check the documentation listed @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/development/public-protocols-support-limitations (check the iCalendar link)!!